# Mouse registering as a keyboard causing the actual keyboard to stop working

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I just bought a new natec mouse to replace my current one, the problem is that once I plug the mouse in my keyboard stops functioning until I unplug the mouse and unplug-replug the keyboard.

After a bit of digging in the logs I found this:

```
Sep 25 21:33:06 kernel: [27809.829326] usb 3-9.3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Sep 25 21:33:06 kernel: [27809.848422] usb 3-9.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1ea7, idProduct=1007
Sep 25 21:33:06 kernel: [27809.848428] usb 3-9.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Sep 25 21:33:06 kernel: [27809.848431] usb 3-9.3: Product: Gaming Mouse
Sep 25 21:33:06 kernel: [27809.848433] usb 3-9.3: Manufacturer: BTL
Sep 25 21:33:06 kernel: [27809.853627] input: BTL Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9.3/3-9.3:1.0/input/input23
Sep 25 21:33:06 kernel: [27809.854130] hid-generic 0003:1EA7:1007.0004: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [BTL Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9.3/input0
Sep 25 21:33:06 kernel: [27809.858826] input: BTL Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9.3/3-9.3:1.1/input/input24
Sep 25 21:33:06 kernel: [27809.859843] hid-generic 0003:1EA7:1007.0005: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [BTL Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9.3/input1
Sep 25 21:33:06 mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9.3"
Sep 25 21:33:06 mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 6 was not an MTP device
```

Specifically I noticed these lines:

```
Sep 25 21:33:06 kernel: [27809.854130] hid-generic 0003:1EA7:1007.0004: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [BTL Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9.3/input0
Sep 25 21:33:06 kernel: [27809.859843] hid-generic 0003:1EA7:1007.0005: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [BTL Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9.3/input1
```

Apparently my mouse is registering itself as a mouse and a keyboard (!!!)

Question 01: Why would it do that? This is a standard mouse with only a forward/back and DPI control buttons

And Question 02: Why is this blocking my actual keyboard from functioning?

I'd post a dmesg with the mouse plugged in but cant use the keyboard to type in the command :p

Comment: Could you please add to your question a [pastebin](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) link where you saved the output of the `udevadm info --export-db` command (when your mouse if plugged in of course)? Based on this result we could write a specific udev rule to avoid that your mouse act/replace your keyboard.

Comment: I realized that you can't type a command. So type `sleep 10 && udevadm info --export-db`. It will give you 10s to plug the mouse

Comment: @SylvainPineau here you go http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=03yYQffM

Comment: Interesting to read: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2119671 (but the proposed solution is to recompile the kernel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was plugging the mouse into a USB 3 port, oddly enough switching to a USB 2 port fixed the issue. The mouse is still registering as both but my actual keyboard is working.